# Design Input Layout that can scroll when Input Panel appear in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I've a problem when design a numeric input form page in windows phone 8.
This form have 5 textboxes with input is numeric type.
I've placed these in scrollviewer but when SIP appear I can't input to 2 last textboxes behind SIP.

I want to design an input form same as UI of

> Add New Contact Name in Windows Phone People Hub.

It can scroll up or down when SIP appear and title of form's still remain.

How can I make it?

Thanks in advances.

Comment: After some research I found the way. It's in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754526/windows-phone-8-scrolling-when-keyboard-visible). Thanks @rashad-annara and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add margin with additional space for your bottom element at the page.

```
<ScrollViewer>
...
<TextBox Margin="0,0,0,200" .../>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Page will be able to scroll down. Adjust bottom margin value for you. Alternatively, you can set the Height of ScrollViewer to the higher value.